# QuerySnapshot filter null - Flutter

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to filter a query on the flutter, but it's returning me null.

```
Future getChamados() async {
    final QuerySnapshot result = await Future.value(Firestore.instance
        .collection("chamados")
        .where("tid", isEqualTo: tid).orderBy('dateTime')
        .getDocuments());

    return result.documents;
  }
```

**FutureBuilder**

```
child: FutureBuilder(
              future: getChamados(),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                  return new Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  );
                } else if (snapshot.data.length == 0 || tid == null || tid == "") {
                  return new Center(
                    child: Text(
                      'Nenhum Chamado.',
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                    ),
                  );
                } else {
                  return ListView.builder(
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return Card(
                            elevation: 8.0,
                            margin: new EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                horizontal: 6.0, vertical: 5.0),
                            child: Container(
                              decoration:
                                  BoxDecoration(color: Color(0xFF00aacb)),
                              child: ListTile(
                                contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                    horizontal: 15.0, vertical: 1.0),...
```

**Error**

> The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building FutureBuilder(dirty, state: _FutureBuilderState#2f75d):
> The getter 'length' was called on null.
> Receiver: null
> Tried calling: length

Comment: Post FutureBuilder's code.

Comment: Added future builder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally you should access the `snapshot.data` when ConnectionState is `ConnectionState.done`. You're trying to access `.legnth` when the `snapshot` is null.

When ConnectionState is `ConnectionState.done`, check the length and conditionally render the widgets. Otherwise show loading widget. Try refactoring `FutureBuilder` like this:

```dart
FutureBuilder(
  future: getChamados(),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done && snapshot.hasData) {
      return snapshot.data.length == 0 || tid == null || tid == ""
        ? ListView.builder(...)
        : Center(
            child: Text(
              'Nenhum Chamado.',
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
            ),
          );
    }
    return CircularProgressIndicator();
  },
),
```

Comment: I changed it as you indicated and you are giving this error: Listen for Query (called where tid == 24082017 order by dateTime, __name__) failed: Status {code = FAILED_PRECONDITION, description = The query requires an index.

Comment: Find the problem. The index needs to be created in the cloud firestore. You can create it through the link generated in the error itself.